# How to find max num of edges given vertices and does not contain length 5?

Tags: graph-theory

What is the greatest possible number of edges in graph with 5 vertices that does not contain
any cycles of length 5? Draw an example of such a graph with this number of edges.

I've tried drawing a graph with 6,7,8,9 and 10 edges. I found out that only 6 and 7 does not have any cycle of length 5 hence 7 is the max num of edge. Is there any formula I can use to confirm this answer?

Comment: How many cycles exist?  How many can be removed by deleting one edge?

Comment: I dont get it, can you elaborate?

Comment: Start with all ten edges.  All the different cycles are there.  If you delete one edge, you removeall cycles that use that edge.  Can you remove all cycles by deleting two edges - leaving 8 - or do you need to remove three?

Comment: I've already tried that, from my graph, i need to remove 3

Comment: But im not sure if it's the correct ans

Comment: What's the $7$-edge graph you've found with no $5$-cycles?